# Objects not aligned like rest of svg

Tags: inkscape, canvas

[image][image]I used Inkscape to make an SVG file for Cricut Canvas. The middle lines are not staying aligned with the rest of the objects and appearing on the bottom instead of in the middle (where it is in Inkscape and in the exported PNG). How do I fix this? [image]

Comment: It would help to have the SVG file, to know which types of objects and transform matrices are in the file.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What do you mean by "the middle lines".  I can't tell what's wrong with your screenshot. What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: Updated it. I'm sorry I thought I uploaded both screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar situation using Silhouette Studio and Inkscape. There may be some "confusion" between the two programs when it comes to SVG standards for fonts or it could be a completely different reason.

My solution was to select the text in Inkscape and use the Path, Object to Path option. This removes the font characteristics but prevents you from directly editing the text in the Cricuit software.